# How to calculate how many coordinates lie between 2 circles of radius 35 and 65?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, counter

I know that the answer should be around 60% of my coordinates lie within this but im only getting about 20%

```
import random
import pylab
import numpy
pylab.close("all")                                              #all import statements
x = [(random.randint(0,100)) for i in range(3000)]      #creating list of x coordinates
y = [(random.randint(0,100)) for j in range(3000)]      #creating list of y coordinates
array=zip(x,y)                                                  #creating an array by combining the x and y coordinates
counter = 0
for i, j in array:
        if 35**2 <= (i**2+j**2) <= 65**2:
                counter+= 1
print counter
```

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know if you are using random numbers?

Comment: over that large a sample it should be much closer to 60% just by looking at the area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if 35**2 <= (i**2+j**2) <= 65**2:
```

This is checking whether the coordinates are between a circle of radius 35 centered at the origin, and a circle of radius 65 centered at the origin.

But since the coordinates you're testing are always in the positive-positive quadrant, only 1/4th as many will fall within the circles as you're expecting.

The simplest fix is to change the `randint` calls to use `(-50, 50)` instead of `(0, 100)`.

Comment: He is checking for circles with radius 35 and radius 65.

Comment: For a circle of radius 65, all points will satisfy x^2+y^2 = 65^2, so that equation is checking circles with those *radii*, not diameters.

Comment: Oops, you're right, so it's just the second problem. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Your area is 10000, in the first quadrant. You're looking at a sample with an area of

```
pi(65**2 - 35**2)/4
```

which is 2356 ... or 23.56% of the total area.  So, you are getting the right answer.

BTW, your code does not need those pylab and numpy imports.

Comment: I think you meant `65**2 - 35**2`, not `*`.

Comment: You are right - I should have displayed the equation as code the first time so that repeated * would be displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize this by `pylab.imshow()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
y, x = np.mgrid[:100, :100]
d = x**2 + y**2
mask = (35**2 <= d) & (d <= 65**2)
pl.imshow(mask, origin="lower")
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Nice visual demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you should be getting less than 30%. You are only filling the first quadrant!

Here's a plot:

[image]

Comment: That plot doesn't show the (quarter-)circles, so it's hard to get much information out of it…

Comment: yes. but the point is that there is nothing in the other 3 quadrants.